# Inject Custom UserManager To Controller Net Core 2.1

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, code-injection, usermanager

I'm having problems trying to inject my UserManager to my controller.

This is my custom UserManager:

```
  public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
    {

        public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser> store, IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor, IPasswordHasher<ApplicationUser> passwordHasher,
             IEnumerable<IUserValidator<ApplicationUser>> userValidators,
             IEnumerable<IPasswordValidator<ApplicationUser>> passwordValidators, ILookupNormalizer keyNormalizer, IdentityErrorDescriber errors,
             IServiceProvider services, ILogger<UserManager<ApplicationUser>> logger)
             : base(store, optionsAccessor, passwordHasher, userValidators, passwordValidators, keyNormalizer, errors, services, logger)
            {

            }


        public async Task<ApplicationUser> FindAsync(string id, string password)
        {
            ApplicationUser user = await FindByIdAsync(id);
            if (user == null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            return await CheckPasswordAsync(user, password) ? user : null;
        }
    }
```

This is my Startup.cs

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.ConfigureCors();
            services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer(options =>
                {
                    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        ValidateIssuer = true,
                        ValidateAudience = true,
                        ValidateLifetime = true,
                        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                        ValidIssuer = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
                        ValidAudience = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
                        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["Jwt:Key"]))
                    };
                });
            // Add framework services.
            services.AddMvc();
            services.AddScoped<ApplicationUserManager>();

            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
            builder.Populate(services);

            // Registering MongoContext. 
            builder.RegisterType<MongoContext>().AsImplementedInterfaces<MongoContext, ConcreteReflectionActivatorData>().SingleInstance();
            //builder.RegisterType<MongoContext>().As<IMongoContext>();

            //Registering ApplicationUserManager. 

   builder.RegisterType<ApplicationUserManager>().As<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>().SingleInstance();
        //builder.RegisterType<ApplicationUserManager>().As<ApplicationUserManager>().SingleInstance();
```

where the two important lines are:
**builder.RegisterType ApplicationUserManager ().As UserManager ApplicationUser ().SingleInstance();**
 **builder.RegisterType ApplicationUserManager ().As ApplicationUserManager ().SingleInstance;**

My controller:  ( I tested it with this 2 constructors, getting same error)

```
 public AccountController(ApplicationUserManager applicationUserManager)
        {
            this.applicationUserManager = applicationUserManager;
        }
        public AccountController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
        {
            this.userManager = userManager;
        }
```

And finally the error:

> Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: None of the constructors
>   found with
>   'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type
>   'VotNetMon.ApplicationUserManager' can be invoked with the available
>   services and parameters: Cannot resolve parameter
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserStore`1[VotNetMon.Entities.ApplicationUser]
>   store' of constructor 'Void
>   .ctor(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserStore`1[VotNetMon.Entities.ApplicationUser],
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IOptions`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityOptions],
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IPasswordHasher`1[VotNetMon.Entities.ApplicationUser],
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserValidator`1[VotNetMon.Entities.ApplicationUser]],
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IPasswordValidator`1[VotNetMon.Entities.ApplicationUser]],
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.ILookupNormalizer,
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityErrorDescriber,
>   System.IServiceProvider,
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[VotNetMon.Entities.ApplicationUser]])'.
>   at
>   Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ReflectionActivator.GetValidConstructorBindings(IComponentContext
>   context, IEnumerable`1 parameters)    at
>   Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ReflectionActivator.ActivateInstance(IComponentContext
>   context, IEnumerable`1 parameters)    at
>   Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1
>   parameters)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error says you have to register the `IUserStore` and other dependencies that are usually registered by the extensions method for AspNetIdentity.

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>();
```

Be aware that this also adds cookie authentication because this is what [asp.net identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio%2Caspnetcore2x) does. If you persist on doing it with autofac, what is totally legit, you should look [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/07774234a652b9ceb2aa5cc50167dda8b15aeb55/src/Identity/IdentityServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L38) which classes have to be registered.

If you want to use identity and jwt together, [here](https://medium.com/@ozgurgul/asp-net-core-2-0-webapi-jwt-authentication-with-identity-mysql-3698eeba6ff8) is a good tutorial that guides you through it.

**Not directly related:**

- Please always use interfaces, don't inject implementations so don't configure your container to resolve implementations.
- There is a new way to use autofac and microsoft's ioc together which is preferred. You can find an example [here](http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html). This is the wanted way for asp.net core >= 2.0.

Comment: Thanks very much. Without autofac, with the tutorial is working fine.   But I dont see which classes I have to register to works with autofac. (IStore, IServiceCollection ... ??)

Comment: I linked it in my answer, it is this link: https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/07774234a652b9ceb2aa5cc50167dda8b15aeb55/src/Identity/IdentityServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L38

Is the source code from microsoft.